# Convert Object to Array

Tags: magento2, object, convert

I try to convert my custom Object to Array.

Here my Object :

```
Namespace\Project\Model\Custom\Object Object
(
    [attr1:protected] => value1
    [attr2:protected] => value2
    [attr3:protected] => value3
)
```

Here, my code to convert :

```
protected function objectToArray($object)
{
    if (!is_object($object) && !is_array($object)) {
        return $object;
    }
    return array_map(array($this, "objectToArray"), (array) $object);
}
```

But the result is :

```
Array
(
    [ * attr1] => value1
    [ * attr2] => value2
    [ * attr2] => value3
)
```

I don't understand why `*` appear in my array key... Any suggestion to remove them ? If possible when I create the array, not after.

Comment: use `$object->toArray()` ,if  $object is  \instance of `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`

Comment: My Object is not an \Magento\Framework\DataObject